# Does Ruby have an "equals-or" operator?

Tags: ruby

Ruby has an "or-equals" operator, `||=`, that's useful for just initializing values. This works beautifully, but from what I can tell, there doesn't appear to be a reversed `||=` operator - that is, set the value IFF the value to be assigned is not `nil`.

Currently the only way I know to do that is something like this:

```
foo = bar if bar
```

Does anyone know if something like this exists, maybe in the form of a gem? If not I'm tempted to make one.

Comment: There is `&&=` but that, like `||=`, works with truthy and falsey values rather than just `nil`.

Comment: There should not be a gem for that, please don't make one :)

Comment: Why should there be a gem for something you have clearly shown has a very simple implementation? Even if there were a gem what syntax would you have it use? Also you do realize in your miniscule example `foo` is now `nil` if `bar` is `nil` or `false` correct? So if `bar` is `nil` then `foo` is `nil` even though `foo` was not assigned `bar`.

Comment: `gem install YOUR_GEM; require 'YOUR_GEM'` is already way more code than would be necessary to implement this everywhere in my code that needs it.

Comment: On top of what everyone is commenting, `||=` is syntax sugar, working at tokenization/parsing level, not evaluation. You cannot rewrite that in Ruby code. You need to dig deeper into C code to do that.